# Ruby: hitting read_timeout even when changed

Tags: ruby, api, http, timeout

From my Ruby code il make a call to a API.
On the testsystem with few data it works without a flaw. 
On the Productive System it works too, but only if not much data is transmitted. If its too much data il get:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in`readuntil'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in`read_status_line'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1437:in`block in transport_request'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in`transport_request'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'

the relevant part in the code seems to be:

```
http = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, :read_timeout => @timeout)
```

i bumped the **@timeout** to 900 and id didnt work eater.

Any ideas how i can get that to work or how i can debug that issue?

Comment: How long does it actually take to query and receive all data from the API? Did you check that?

Comment: It takes around 10 minutes. But with 15 minutes my setting should be safe.

Comment: When do you get the timeout? After around 15 minutes or earlier – for example after 90 seconds?

Comment: @spickermann I underestimated the duration. The script takes almost 16 minutes. after I've observed that, I altered the timeout again to 30 Minutes. I don't get the error anymore, but now the next *each* statement fails 18 Minutes after start, because it has no return values *undefined method `each_value' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)*

Comment: There is no `each_value` in your question. You will need to add the relevant code to your question. What do you want to do your application instead when it runs into the timeout? Do nothing? Raise an error? Use a fallback?